# Calcuate Average Days Between of a List of Dates in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a simple List. Each date is arbitrary, but is in chronlogical order.

I would like to determine the average of day span between dates.

For example:

- 01/01/2022
- 01/02/2022
- 01/04/2022

...should return an average of `1.5`. (The denominator in this case is the timespans between dates. In this case, there are only 2 timespans between the 3 dates)

Because there's `1` day between 1/1 and 1/2, and `2` days between 1/2 and 1/4.

```
(1 day + 2 days) / 2 timespans = 1.5 avg
```

Is there a LINQ way of doing this, without having to manually iterate through each list item in list?

Comment: Pretty sure the avg on your example is 1 not 1.5, right? `1 day` + `2 days` / `3 dates` = `3/3` = `1`

Comment: No. The denominator in this case is the timespans between dates. In this case, there are only 2 timespans between the 3 dates.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if there's a better way of doing it, but here's one that I just put together, and it seems to work reliably for me

```cs
var avg = myList.Zip(myList.Skip(1), (dt1, dt2) => dt2 - dt1).Average(dt => dt.Days);
```

EDIT: just checked the docs, and the .Zip method isn't in versions prior to .NET 4

Answer (score 1):

This will do it iterating over the List only once:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, dates.Count() - 1)
    .Select(i => (dates[i] - dates[i - 1]).TotalDays)
    .Average();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
double aveDays= (days.Last()-days.First()).Days /((double)days.Count-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0) and [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-5.0) to get the total number of days and then divide by `Count - 1` which is the number of gaps in between.

```
var avg = dates.Zip(dates.Skip(1), (dt1, dt2) => dt2 - dt1)
  .Aggregate(0d, (a, dt) => a + dt.Days)
  / (dates.Count - 1);
```

Notice that I'm using `0d` because otherwise it'd result into an integer number (`1`) instead of a double (`1.5`).